# How to send correct date format from dateTimePicker to MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

This is the format used in my MySql database: 2018-04-22.

In my C# form, I pick the value form dataTimePicker:

```
String data1 = dataTimePicker1.Text;
```

Then send it with parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = data1;
```

I changed dataTimePicker1 custom format to: `yyyy-MM-dd` but it seems it still sends the wrong format: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: use `dataTimePicker1.Value` instead

Comment: what is the data type of column in sql table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `Text` property of the `DateTimePicker`. Use it's `Value` property instead. The `Value` property is of type `DateTime`, so when you pass it as a parameter to the database, you don't need to worry about display format (since `DateTime` doesn't store display format).

```
var data1 = dataTimePicker1.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = data1;
```